# Arrays and implementing my CDList methods in my main program?

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

This might be little complicated but I will try my best to explain

well let me first put my CDList class

**MAIN:**now this is what the main program is asking me 
The main program is to test the CDList capabilities. You may hard-code the 5 calls
to add, then add() will prompt the user for inputs. Your main program should call all of 
the CDlist public methods, and produce labeled output explainging clearly what the Page 2 of 2
output is attempting to demonstrate.
and this is what I have for main so far.. just to test the add method from CDList...

**OUTPUTS:**
The outputs for this program are a complete captured test session, with the main 
program producing the labels saying, “Testing delete:” (or whatever), then showing the 
results. Make the results CLEAR to the grader. You are to 1) add 5 CDs (having plausible 
data, with at least 3 tracks each) to the CDList, 2) display the data sorted by artist, 3) 
display the list after sorting by title, and 4) show the list before and after deleting one of 
the CDs from the list. For full credit, the output must be clearly labeled, and the CD list 
display must be neat and easily readable.

EDIT 5: MY CDList CLASS

```
 package cd;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CDList {

    public int cdnum;
    private CD[] CDlist;
    private int front, rear;
    //private String artist;      
    //private String title;

    public CDList(int size) {
        CDlist = new CD[size];
        cdnum = 0;
        front = 0;
        rear = size - 1;
    }

   public boolean add() {
        boolean result = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Artist name and the CD title: ");
        CD yourCD = new CD(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the number of songs: ");
        int songNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the songs: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= songNum; i++) {
            yourCD.addTrack(input.nextLine());
        }
        CDlist[cdnum] = yourCD;


        if (rear == front) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            if (CDlist[rear] != null) {
                rear--;
            } else {
                CDlist[rear] = yourCD;
            }
            result = true;
        }

        return result;    

    }

    public void delete() {
        Scanner deleteInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which artist you would like to delete? ");
        System.out.println("Enter artist name and title to be deleted:");
        String artist = deleteInput.nextLine();
        String title = deleteInput.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i <= CDlist.length - 1; i++) {

            if ((CDlist[i].getArtist().equals(artist))
                    && (CDlist[i].getTitle().equals(title))) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + CDlist[i].getArtist());
                System.out.println(CDlist[i].getTitle());

                if (deleteInput.nextInt() == 1) {
                    CDlist[i] = null;
                    cdnum--;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("CD not found in the list.");
            }
        }


    }

    public void SortArtist() {

        CD temp = new CD(" "," ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= CDlist.length; i++) {
            if (i < CDlist.length-1) {
                if (CDlist[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDlist[i+1].getArtist())<0){
                temp = CDlist[i];
                CDlist[i] = CDlist[i + 1];
                CDlist[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    public void SortTitle() {
        CD temp1 ;
        for (int i = cdnum; i > 0; i--) {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (CDlist[i].getTitle().compareTo(CDlist[i+1].getTitle())<0) {
                    x = j;
                }
            }
            temp1 = CDlist[x];
            CDlist[x] = CDlist[i];
            CDlist[i] = temp1;
        }
    }

    public void Display() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= cdnum; i++) {
            while (CDlist[i] == null) {
                i++;
            }
            CDlist[i].display();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return cdnum;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT IM GETTING WITH ERROR:

> Would you like to add a new CD Please enter the Artist name and the CD
>   title:  eminem  recovery Enter the number of songs:  3 Enter the name
>   of the songs:  space bound not afraid love the way you lie Please
>   enter the Artist name and the CD title:  micheal jackson  thriller
>   Enter the number of songs:  3 Enter the name of the songs:  beat it 
>   thriller baby be mine Please enter the Artist name and the CD title: 
>   sean paul tomahawk technique Enter the number of songs:  3 Enter the
>   name of the songs:  she doesn't mind put it on you body Please enter
>   the Artist name and the CD title:  Manafest Glory Enter the number of
>   songs:  3 Enter the name of the songs:  where are you runaway dreams
>   Please enter the Artist name and the CD title:  kj-52 collaborations
>   Enter the number of songs:  3 Enter the name of the songs:  dear slim
>   where were you why
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   cd.CDList.SortArtist(CDList.java:86)  at cd.Main.main(Main.java:17)
>   Java Result: 1
>
> and this is line 86: 
>   if (CDlist[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDlist[i+1].getArtist())<0)
>
> and this line 17
>   and this line 17: list.SortArtist();
>
> ---

Main

```
   package cd;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Would you like to add a new CD");
        CDList list = new CDList(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.add();
        }
        list.SortArtist();
        list.Display();
        list.SortTitle();
        list.Display(); 
        list.delete();
        list.Display();


    }
}
```

EDIT3: MY CD CLASS

```
package cd;
```

public class CD {

```
private String artist;      //stores artist name
private String title;       //stores CD title
private String track;
private tracklist list;            //tracklist variable

// constructor, sets artist and title, creates tracklist array
public CD(String artistname, String titlename) {
    artist = artistname;
    title = titlename;
    list = new tracklist();

}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

// adds a new track, return true if less than 100, flase if no space
public boolean addTrack(String trackinfo) {
    if (list.count < 100) {
        list.add(trackinfo);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int numTracks() {
    return list.count;
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("Artist:  \t" + artist);
    System.out.println("CD Title: \t" + title);
    list.display(5);
}
```

}

EDIT4: Tracklist class

```
    package cd;

public class tracklist {

    public String[] lists;  //array
    private String tNum;
    private String tName;
    int numElements;        // Counter to keep track of the used slots
    int count;              //loop counter

// constructor, creats array for tracks
    public tracklist() {

        numElements = 0;
        lists = new String[100];

    }

// adds tracks to tracklist
    public boolean add(String track) {
        if (numElements < 100) {
            lists[numElements] = track;
            numElements++;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The tracklist is full.");
            return false;
        }
    }

//returns the number of elements in array
    public int count() {
        return numElements;
    }

//displays tracklist in required form
    public void display(int indent) {
        tName = "%" + indent + "s";
        tNum = "%" + (indent - 2) + "d";

        System.out.printf(tName, "Track #");
        System.out.println("\t\tSong Title");


        for (count = 0; count < numElements; count++) {
            System.out.printf(tNum, count + 1);
            System.out.println("\t\t" + lists[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is wrong

```
 int songNum = input.nextByte();
```

you need to use `nextInt()`

I haven't found **main method or any static block** in your code.

You haven't called he add method also

```
 CD[i]= new CDList(5);

CD[i].add() or  call add() method in the CD constructor
```

Add

Your  Complete Working Code:

**Change SortArtist like this**

public void SortArtist() {

```
    CD temp = new CD(" ", " ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= CDlist.length; i++) {
        if(i<CDlist.length-1){
        if (CDlist[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDlist[i + 1].getArtist()) < 0) {
            temp = CDlist[i];
            CDlist[i] = CDlist[i + 1];
            CDlist[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

---

**Add method:**:

```
  public boolean add() {
        boolean result = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Artist name and the CD title: ");
        CD yourCD = new CD(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the number of songs: ");
        int songNum = input.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the songs: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= songNum; i++) {
            yourCD.addTrack(input.nextLine());
        }
        CDlist[cdnum] = yourCD;


        if (rear == front) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            if (CDlist[rear] != null) {
                rear--;
            } else {
                CDlist[rear] = yourCD;
            }
            result = true;
        }
        return result;    

    }
```

---

And importantly

Change Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


   System.out.println("Would you like to add a new CD");
 CDList list=new CDList(2);  // Two is the No of CDs you can prompt the user to enter by reading the input and pass it to the constructor
    for (int i=0; i < 2 ; i++) {
        list.add();
    }   
    list.SortArtist();
    list.Display();

}
```

}

**Expected output**:

```
Would you like to add a new CD
Please enter the Artist name and the CD title: 
Ram
Charan
Enter the number of songs: 
1
Enter the name of the songs: 
song1
Please enter the Artist name and the CD title: 
Ram
Racha
Enter the number of songs: 
2
Enter the name of the songs: 
song1
song2
Artist:     Ram
CD Title:   Racha
Track #     Song Title
  1     
  2     song1
  3     song2
```

Comment: Oh okay. thanks fixed it... but now what do I do to implement my my add method in my main program?

Comment: well when I put CD[i].add() im getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable add
  location: class cd.CDList
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Java Result: 1

Comment: another problem is when I do the add call.. I want to output to be something like this Artist: (user input) Title: (User input).. how ?

Comment: I'm having errors... How should I post the errors and the new code lines?

Comment: Sorry to bother you... but the problem is in my methods delete, SortArtist, SortTitle... I keep receiving errors...

Comment: alright yes I did that... but I still get errors from SortArtist method

Comment: do I do that for both the SortArtist and SortTitle?

Comment: I did what you told me but I'm still receiving error...am I calling SortArtist correctly? CD[i].SortArtist();      and this the error im getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cd.CDList.SortArtist(CDList.java:83)
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:62)
Java Result: 1

Comment: line no 55? Let me edit the question again and show you what I have in my main program...

Comment: @user2168344 In your for use  CDlist.length instead of cdnum

Comment: same error i'm getting even when i fixed it to CDlist.length... this is the error....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cd.CDList.SortArtist(CDList.java:83)
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: This is line 83: if (CDlist[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDlist[i + 1].getArtist()) < 0)

Comment: posted my CD class and the output

Comment: Plus I want to input 5 CDs first... why is it just allowing me to put on only and then it goes to sorting and get that error

Comment: please bro... I really appreciate your help bare with me. I will post the track list class

Comment: Alright I posted tracklist class... PLEASE bare with me.. thank you for being patient...

Comment: please hurry.. I need to figure this thing out ASAP.. thank you

Comment: and please remember this is how my output should look like... please help me..You are to 1) add 5 CDs (having plausible 
data, with at least 3 tracks each) to the CDList, 2) display the data sorted by artist, 3) 
display the list after sorting by title, and 4) show the list before and after deleting one of 
the CDs from the list

Comment: alright I added and now it looks like this.... for (int i = 0; i <= songNum; i++) {
            yourCD.addTrack(input.nextLine());
            CDlist[cdnum]=yourCD;
        } is that correct

Comment: but I'm adding multiple CDs... because it asks about 5-6 times for the CD name and etc...

Comment: Please don't abandon me please... I'm still getting errors which I don't know how to fix

Comment: copy and paste my add method where?

Comment: Hmmm its till giving me an error... now should int=songNum = input.nextInt() instead of byte?

Comment: Just a for loop to accept multiple Artists and title because you can't sort with a single CD

Comment: this line 34 is giving errors :  int songNum = input.nextInt();

Comment: @user2168344 I'll paste complete code, your code is working wait 40 mins, I will had my lunch and get back to you

Comment: Alright thank you very much.. is it possible in anyway to paste the code now PLEASE!!! ??

Comment: please don't forget about me... I'm still stuck

Comment: @user2168344 posted your answer along with the output

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH... I'm testing it right now.. now for the other methods i just put list.whatevermethod correct?

Comment: oh no... my program crashed right when I was writing my input for the second CD I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1924)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1883)
 at cd.CDList.add(CDList.java:31)
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Line 31 is : int songNum = input.nextByte();... and Line 15 is: list.add();

Comment: I got you brother, problem is you may give wrong input to it. InputmisMatch error will when you give wrong input

Comment: First two inputs are string  and the next one is int, it should be number. check with the inputs You will find in the output I have paste

Comment: You have given a wrong print statement brother, do what I say give the inputs I have given in the above output, This will work for sure. First two are Artist and title next one is number and remaing are string

Comment: Alright this time I made sure I did everything correct... and I inputted 5 CD information.. but then at the last CD I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cd.CDList.SortArtist(CDList.java:86)
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Java Result: 1 Line 86 is : if (CDlist[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDlist[i+1].getArtist())<0){ ... and line 17:  list.SortArtist();

Comment: @user2168344 number in  CDList list=new CDList(2); constructor should be there in for loop also in your Main.java and also make sure that you've entered the right text. I have Tested with 5 it is working perfectly

Comment: I have the same code you posted for main, I just changed it to 5 instead of 2... So I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Both in constructor and for loop right.....Remove all your old code and paste your new updated code in your question..Along with inputs and output

Comment: Alright I'm going input the data and show you what I get in my out put

Comment: @user2168344 where is Main.java

Comment: @user2168344 Add this   cdnum+=1; after this line CDlist[cdnum] = yourCD; in add method

Comment: is that going to fix it? should I test?

Comment: @user2168344 I would like to know is it my problem or your problem..I was good enough to spend my time, What type of question is that...Am i posted that for no reason..?

Comment: oh man I got a big mess... the are not in order.. they are in reverse order

Comment: I'm really sorry... please bare with me sir... I apologize for bothering you... I'm really sorry please bare with me.. I appreciate everything you have done... please continue helping me.. you got me this far and I really appreciate it

Comment: Change symbol in your SortArtist() ie. < to >

Comment: I'm sorry but how does that work? I'm not familiar with <to>... im really sorry.. is it possible you give me the code to put? im sorry

Comment: this is my output... and as you can see they are not sorted and there is also an error I will post it in two comments: Artist:   micheal jackson
CD Title:  thriller
Track #  Song Title
  1  
  2  baby be mine
  3  thriller
  4  beat it
Artist:   sean paul 
CD Title:  tomahawk
Track #  Song Title
  1  
  2  body
  3  she doesn't mind
  4  put it on you
Artist:   manafest
CD Title:  glory
Track #  Song Title
  1  
  2  runaway
  3  dreams
  4  where are you

Comment: Artist:   kj-52
CD Title:  collaboration
Track #  Song Title
  1  
  2  where were you
  3  dear slim
  4  why
Artist:   eminem 
CD Title:  recovery
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
Track #  Song Title
  1  
  2  space bound
  3  not afraid
  4  love the way you lie
 at cd.CDList.Display(CDList.java:113)
 at cd.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Change cdnum to CDlist.length in the for loop in display method

Comment: it still giving me the same wrong order and with the error between the last output... again please bare with me... I'm really sorry please bare with me..

Comment: @user2168344 I went outside, remove = symbol in for loop of display method

Comment: now the problem is also with the SortTitle method.. im geting error

Comment: @user2168344 do same modifications that you have done for SortArtist() method

Comment: but what I have is different from SortArtist... I cant do the same modifications... public void SortTitle() {
        CD temp1= new CD(" ", " ");
        for (int i = cdnum; i > 0; i--) {
            int x = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (CDlist[i].getTitle().compareTo(CDlist[i + 1].getTitle()) < 0) {
                    x = j;
                }
            }
            temp1 = CDlist[x];
            CDlist[x] = CDlist[i];
            CDlist[i] = temp1;
        }
    }

Comment: @user2168344 Simply copy paste SortArtist() method and change the getArtist() to getTitle() in if condition

Comment: alright thank you... Im testing now... and for the delete... do you think it is good sir?

Comment: @user2168344  I'll recommend to display the Artist name of all cds in your list and then ask user for input i.e switch statement with option1, 2 3 etc

Comment: alright, so i have to add switch statement in my delete. would you be able to provide with the example for the switch statement for my delete method?

Comment: @user2168344 sorry I was busy with my work...That is so simple try to search in google learn by your self. Don't forgot to accept the anbswer

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you very much, I hope that we could get in contact more, and I would love to learn from you... thank you.. but just one last more favor... I already have my delete method... do I need to really do switch statement??...

Comment: @user2168344 I guess your delete method will work. Be Active in Stackoverflow, it will fetch you lot of knowledge. You can accept this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer, because it will help for others

Comment: Bro.... Sorry to bother you... but would you please please help me write the delete method... I keep getting errors... please you have the code here.. can improve it for me please...